# Laravel Production Server Issues

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

As part of a project I am working on, it must be developed on a live server rather than a virtual host and I have run into some issues that I can't resolve.

The first is that bootstrap is not working from the default layouts file you get from running make:auth.

When I view the source, the link to the stylesheet is prefixed with localhost:(port_number) rather than the url for the website, I have changed the url in the .env file and also changed to default in the config.app file. Yet this still persists, any ideas how to solve this.

The second issue I am running into is when I try to click on the default auth login or register links it will preface the url with the same localhost, however if I replace the localhost with the website url it will return an error that auth.login or auth.register is not found, even though the files are on the server and showing in the ide perfectly fine?

Routes file as follows

```
        Auth::routes();

        //Pages Routings
        Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
        Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
        Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
```

If anyone could shed some light on these, I would be very grateful as I have spent longer than I care to admit trying to figure it out, thanks :)

Comment: also check the `APP_URL` entry in your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server has mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will have a look and get back to you